# Troubleshooting RavenDB Random Slowness

Tags: c#, wpf, ravendb

I have a WPF application that uses RavenDB. On one of the windows I can hit the Refresh button repeatedly to update a grid. Each refresh causes a RavenDB query. What's odd is that every now and then the query will take a long time. For example, I can hit the Refresh button seven times in a row, and the grid will refresh in less than a second. Then, on the 8th attempt, it will take 12 seconds. Then, I can hit Refresh 11 more times, and it runs quickly again, but on the 12th time, it takes 12 seconds again. It's pretty consistent this way. It seems to always take 12 seconds every time there is a delay. What is that?

Here is the query:

```
IQueryable<EntityBase> installationSummaries =
    QueryAndSetEtags(session => session.Query<InstallationSummary>()
    .Include(x => x.ApplicationServerId)
    .Include(x => x.ApplicationWithOverrideVariableGroup.ApplicationId)
    .Include(x => x.ApplicationWithOverrideVariableGroup.CustomVariableGroupId)
    .Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResults())
    .OrderByDescending(summary => summary.InstallationStartUtc)
    .Take(numberToRetrieve)
    );

    HydrateInstallationSummaries(installationSummaries);

    return installationSummaries.AsEnumerable().Cast<InstallationSummary>();
```

The delay is always on this line of code (entityBases is the return value from the above query):

```
List<EntityBase> entityBaseList = entityBases.ToList();
```

**What's the right way to troubleshoot something like this in RavenDB?** I'm not sure what to try next.

**Note: This code hasn't changed in a long time. I'm now using RavenDB 960. This never happened with RavenDB 573.**

**Edit -- Additional code to show what else is happening around this query.**

```
    private static void HydrateInstallationSummaries(IQueryable<EntityBase> installationSummaries)
    {
        // Note: We use session.Load() below so that we get the information from the session, and not another trip to the DB.
        foreach (InstallationSummary summary in installationSummaries)
        {
            HydrateInstallationSummary(summary);
        }
    }

    private static void HydrateInstallationSummary(InstallationSummary summary)
    {
        if (summary == null) { return; }

        summary.ApplicationServer =
            QuerySingleResultAndSetEtag(session => session.Load<ApplicationServer>(summary.ApplicationServerId))
            as ApplicationServer;

        summary.ApplicationWithOverrideVariableGroup.Application =
            QuerySingleResultAndSetEtag(session => session.Load<Application>(summary.ApplicationWithOverrideVariableGroup.ApplicationId))
            as Application;

        if (summary.ApplicationWithOverrideVariableGroup.CustomVariableGroupId == null) { return; }

        summary.ApplicationWithOverrideVariableGroup.CustomVariableGroup =
            QuerySingleResultAndSetEtag(session =>
            {
                if (session.Advanced.IsLoaded(summary.ApplicationWithOverrideVariableGroup.CustomVariableGroupId))
                {
                    return session.Load<CustomVariableGroup>(summary.ApplicationWithOverrideVariableGroup.CustomVariableGroupId);
                }
                return null;  // Note: We can be missing a custom variable in the session because someone deleted it.
                ;
            })
            as CustomVariableGroup;
    }
```

**And here is QueryAndSetEtags():**

```
    protected static IQueryable<EntityBase> QueryAndSetEtags(Func<IDocumentSession, IQueryable<EntityBase>> func)
    {
        if (func == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("func"); }

        IQueryable<EntityBase> entities = func.Invoke(_session);
        SetEtags(entities, _session);
        return entities;
    }

    protected static void SetEtags(IEnumerable<EntityBase> entityBases, IDocumentSession session)
    {
        foreach (EntityBase entityBase in entityBases)
        {
            SetEtag(entityBase, session);
        }
    }

    protected static void SetEtag(EntityBase entityBase, IDocumentSession session)
    {
        entityBase.Etag = (Guid)session.Advanced.GetEtagFor(entityBase);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got a lot of custom code in that example, so it's hard to know exactly what is going on.  But I'm pretty sure the problem revolves around this line:

```
.Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResults())
```

This is not something you want in a production query.  It is primary there for unit testing.

Try removing that line entirely, or if you really do need to wait, then specify a cutoff point instead, such as:

```
.Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfNow())
```

And if possible, consider upgrading to RavenDB 2.0.  It has much better performance and features.

Comment: Thanks, Matt, but that didn't help. I removed that line entirely, and it ran quickly the first two times, but the third time it took 12 seconds again. I should probably upgrade to RavenDB 2.0, but I just upgraded to 960. Not looking forward to another change...

Comment: Well, then I need to know more about what you're doing in `QueryAndSetEtags` and `HydrateInstallationSummaries`.  Also, I'm not sure why you would do `.AsEnumerable().Cast<InstallationSummary>()` - The results should already be of type `InstallationSummary`, and by calling `AsEnumerable` you are invoking the query - making it pointless to use `IQueryable`, and the later call to `ToList` is not doing very much.

Comment: Those are good points, and I actually already have ToDos in my code to fix those things. If you're still interested in helping, I posted more code in my question. And +1 for the tips and help, regardless if you decide to keep helping me... :)

Comment: I read through your updated code.  You're doing a lot manually for etags that could be done with listeners, as described [here](http://ravendb.net/kb/16/using-optimistic-concurrency-in-real-world-scenarios), but that's not the cause of the slowness.  The query is executed when you enter the `foreach` block in `HydrateInstallationSummaries`. So if you're seeing slowness later, it's not likely coming from Raven.

Comment: Also - your hydration code appears to be embedding several documents into one larger document which was also loaded.  Raven will see the hydration as changes to the outer document because it is tracked in session.  I don't think that's what you want.  You should consider a projection, transformation, or at least some other external container object that is not session tracked.

Comment: Thanks again, Matt. As far as seeing slowness later, I'm not seeing any slowness other than at the `foreach` line. So the slowness is when the query is executed.

Comment: Ok, I thought you were saying it came from the .ToList() statement.  At this point, I would ask for support on the google group or for commercial support from Hibernating Rhinos.  There is more going on with your server than you can repo in this question.